# Django - Loading templates from different project folder?

Tags: django, apache

Issue: Beta site is pulling from primary site templates folder,
below is a skeleton structure of the site folder structure - store is the hosted project dir for DOMAIN.com
beta/store goes to beta.DOMAIN.com

the site is hosted

Dir Structure

```
Project/
  apache
    site.wsgi
  beta
    apache
      site.wsgi
    logs
    store
      [APPS]
      media
      templates
  logs
  store
    [APPS]
    media
    templates
```

---

### settings.py (relavent portions)

```
import os

DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'templates/'),
)
```

---

console from PROJECT/beta/store

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DIRNAME
'/home/python/mykornhole/beta/store'
>>> settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
('/home/python/mykornhole/beta/store/../store/templates/',)
>>>
```

**Question:** How can I get the beta site to render templates from the proper directory?

The Console shows that the TEMPLATE_DIRS directory is the proper one, but when I change something on a template from /PROJECT/store/templates it renders on the beta page, when I make a change to a /PROJECT/beta/store/templates template it is ignored

th media folder and others are showing updates, just note the templates...

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem a bit more. It is not clear for me. Do you want to load the templates of the beta app from the primary app?

Comment: @luc -- I think the problem is that the 2nd to the last line of the console should be ('/home/python/mykornhole/beta/store/templates/',), not '../store'.

Comment: Could you be more clear about your problem?

Comment: As others have said, what is the question?

Comment: I defined the question, how can I get it to render templates from the correct dir, and vise-versa why is it loading templates from another project dir?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion may be related to having your beta site as a subdirectory of your production(?) site.

What is the value of DIRNAME? The TEMPLATE_DIRS value of`'/home/python/mykornhole/beta/store/../store/templates/'` would seem to indicate DIRNAME is '`/home/python/mykornhole/beta/store/../store/'` which doesn't feel right.

In the future I recommend keeping beta and production in entirely separate directory trees.